Is this kind of deep linking possible on react native expo?
I want to integrate branch.io into the app for deferred deep linking in my react native expo app.
Basically, users will share a page(website preview) from the app. Then users without the app installed will visit the webpage and there'll be a "Create my own item" button there.
When they click the button, if the app isn't installed, they will be redirected to the device's app store(playstore or appstore) and a userId(of the person that shared the URL) should be stored somewhere till they open the app and it should be able to be retrieved after installation of the app.
The userId in question will be gotten from the site and is dynamic.

No, this is not possible. Branch does not currently support applications that use Expo officially now.
See the official help document: https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native-advanced-features#expo-framework

Thank you for the response. But is what I described even possible? I need to know that
